# How to integration test an Asp.Net Core client app that relies on independent Asp.Net Core Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have two Asp.Net Core systems, which are completely independent, meaning that they reside on different web domains. Still, they are in the same solution in Visual Studio. Both Asp.Net Core systems would be hosted, for example, on these two domains:

https://client-localhost:8080 and https://api-localhost:8081

where the client app makes calls to many different routes of the Api domain in order to get data.

I have no problems doing integration tests (using NUnit) for the Api system, for example:

```
// Integration Test for the Api

[TestFixture]
class IntegrationTestShould
{
    public TestServer GetTestServerInstance()
    {
        return new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestServerStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("TestInMemoryDb"));
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ReturnProductDataFromTestInMemoryDb()
    {
        using (var server = GetTestServerInstance())
        {
            var client = server.CreateClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/products"); // equivalent to: https://api-localhost:8081/products
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.AreEqual("{ Shows product data coming from the Api }", responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do a proper integration test for the client app, I would like to make Api calls from the client app to the Api.

**Is it possible to create one single test method in which I can start both test servers (client and Api) and consume the api through my client?**

I can imagine, for example, to inject the Api test server into the client test server so that I can consume the Api through my client app.

Does something like the following exist?

```
// Integration test for the client that relies on the Api

[TestFixture]
class IntegrationTestShould
{
    public TestServer GetApiTestServerInstance()
    {
        return new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<ApiTestServerStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("TestInMemoryDb"));
    }

    public TestServer GetClientTestServerInstance()
    {
        return new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<ClientTestServerStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("Development"));
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShowProductsFromApiAtClientLevel()
    {
        using (var apiServer = GetApiTestServerInstance())
        using (var clientServer = GetClientTestServerInstance())
        {
            var client = clientServer.CreateClient(apiServer);
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/products"); // equivalent to: https://client-localhost:8080/products which relies on https://api-localhost:8081/products
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.AreEqual("{ Shows product data coming from the api at client level }",
                 responseString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Does something like the following exist?` What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mjwills simple, but powerful question, I simply tested the code as it was and there were compile errors. But this got the stone rolling and I tried and failed until I figured it out.

What I basically did is inject the instantiated HttpClient of the ApiServer into my client app backend where an HttpRequest is made to the ApiServer. So whenever the client app wants to make an api call to the api server, it does so by using the injected HttpClient of the ApiServer.

Here is a snapshot of my Integration test and a little bit of my client app code that should anyone guide into the right direction:

```
// My abbreviated and redacted integration test using NUnit
[TestFixture]
public class IntegrationTestShould
{
    public TestServer GetApiTestServerInstance()
    {
        return new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<ApiTestServerStartup>()
            .UseEnvironment("TestInMemoryDb"));
    }

    public TestServer GetClientTestServerInstance(TestServer apiTestServer)
    {
        // In order to get views rendered:
        // 1. ContentRoot folder must be set when TestServer is built (or views are not found)
        // 2. .csproj file of test project must be adjusted, see http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1420/integration-testing-aspnet-core (or references for view rendering are missing)

        var apiHttpClient = apiTestServer.CreateClient();
        apiHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://api-localhost:8081");
        var currentDirectory =
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory));
        var contentRoot = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"..\..\ProjectThatContainsViews"));
        return new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<ClientTestServerStartup>()
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
            // register instantiated apiHttpClient in client app
            .ConfigureServices(collection => collection.AddSingleton(apiHttpClient))
            .UseEnvironment("ClientTestServer"));
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task CorrectlyReturnProductsViewResult()
    {
        using (var apiServer = GetApiTestServerInstance())
        using (var clientServer = GetClientTestServerInstance(apiServer))
        {
            var clientHttpClient = clientServer.CreateClient();
            var response = await clientHttpClient.GetAsync("/products");
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Assert.AreEqual("text/html; charset=utf-8",
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }
    }
}

// My heavily abbreviated and redacted client app backend
public class HttpRequestBuilder
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public HttpRequestBuilder(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // get instantiated apiHttpClient from client app dependency container (when running in test environment)
        // or create new one (the case when running in environment other than test)
        _httpClient = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(HttpClient)) as HttpClient ?? new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync()
    {
        // Setup request
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(@"https://api-localhost:8081/products")
        };

        // Send request
        var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        // should have returned product data from api
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

        return result; // api product data processed further at client app level
    }
}
```